# how Magento can be made more secure for the client?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

how Magento can be made more secure for the client

Comment: Use latest magento version or install all required security patches

Answer (score 1):

- Always keep Magento updated with **latest security patches**.
- Use **captcha** for all pages with **forms**.
- **Install SSL** on the server and configure Magento to use HTTPS.
- **Don't modify core Magento files directly**.
- Regularly **scan store** for malicious scripts.
- **Change Magento admin panel URL** and **keep all** (cPanel, FTP, ssh, Magento admin panel) users' **passwords secret**.

I hope you would be satisfied with my answer.